# How to add a score text in a unity game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a Unity Game , so basically it is a school project ,but next level . I build an arena , and two balls on it . The balls have to push each other on the arena and the last one standing on the arena wins . But i am stuck with my code ... i want that the first ball who falls down , immediatly to respawn the both balls in the respawn point , and then the score to go higher with 1 point every time one of the balls falls down. It seems so difficult for me and i am struggling with it. If anybody cand save me i will be happy ! Thanks !! <3

I tried a lot of methods but the only bug i have is that if a ball falls down , the game automatically spawns a lot of balls in the place the ball has fallen . And after 1 minute my map is full of balls .... and i do not want that to happen. So please i am asking for your help !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two ball objects, you could make a `Player.cs` script, that is applied to the two balls. The script could have the following fields:

- The other player object
- The player's score object
- The position on which the player is to respawn

Then, inside your `Update` method, you could check whether the ball has fallen below a certain Y value. If so, it can get the other player's score object, and increase the number on it. After that, just set the position of the current object to the specified position.

Currently, I can't provide any specific APIs or code, since I don't have Unity installed, but I'll be sure to edit the answer as soon as it installs.

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to do, my advice is to create an empty GameObject, add a collider, and activate the isTriggered property. To make a previously prepared vector2 or vector3 the position of the players when one of the players is triggered and to set all the forces affecting the rigidbody of the players to 0 . You can also figure out which player to score according to the tag of the triggered GameObject every time it is triggered.

I'm not a professional but I hope it helped.

Comment: Also for the last problem, don't instantiate the players again and again, I guess that's what caused the problem.
if you are not already doing this.
  If you are making a system where you protect the old object while reloading the scene, I can give you a small code for you. I had a similar problem before.